# How to convert Array of Json Strings into Dataset of specific columns in Spark 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a `Dataset<String> ds` which consists of json rows.

**Sample Json Row (This is just an example of one row in the dataset)**

```
[ 
    "{"name": "foo", "address": {"state": "CA", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "english", "year": 2016}]}", 
    "{"name": "bar", "address": {"state": "OH", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "math", "year": 2017}]}"

]
```

ds.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to convert into the following dataset using Spark 2.2.0

```
name  |             address               |  docs 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"foo" | {"state": "CA", "country": "USA"} | [{"subject": "english", "year": 2016}]
"bar" | {"state": "OH", "country": "USA"} | [{"subject": "math", "year": 2017}]
```

Preferably Java but Scala is also fine as long as there are functions available in Java API

Here is what I tried so far

```
val df = Seq("""["{"name": "foo", "address": {"state": "CA", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "english", "year": 2016}]}", "{"name": "bar", "address": {"state": "OH", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "math", "year": 2017}]}" ]""").toDF
```

df.show(false)

```
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|["{"name": "foo", "address": {"state": "CA", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "english", "year": 2016}]}", "{"name": "bar", "address": {"state": "OH", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "math", "year": 2017}]}" ]|
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround in Java. I hope this helps.

Create a Bean class (TempBean in my case)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TempBean
    {
        String name;
        Map<String, String> address;
        List<Map<String, String>> docs;
        public String getName()
            {
                return name;
            }
        public void setName(String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
        public Map<String, String> getAddress()
            {
                return address;
            }
        public void setAddress(Map<String, String> address)
            {
                this.address = address;
            }
        public List<Map<String, String>> getDocs()
            {
                return docs;
            }
        public void setDocs(List<Map<String, String>> docs)
            {
                this.docs = docs;
            }

    }
```

Use the following code with below imports:

```
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> dfList = ds.collectAsList(); //using your Dataset<String>
List<TempBean> tempList = new ArrayList<TempBean>();
try
    {
        for (String json : dfList)
            {
             List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
             for(Map<String,Object> map : mapList)
             {
                TempBean temp = new TempBean();
                temp.setName(map.get("name").toString());
             temp.setAddress((Map<String,String>)map.get("address"));
             temp.setDocs((List<Map<String,String>>)map.get("docs"));
             tempList.add(temp);
             }
            }
    }
catch (JsonParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (JsonMappingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Create dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> dff = spark.createDataFrame(tempList, TempBean.class);
```

Show database

```
dff.show(false);
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+
|address                         |docs                                   |name|
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+
|Map(state -> CA, country -> USA)|[Map(subject -> english, year -> 2016)]|foo |
|Map(state -> OH, country -> USA)|[Map(subject -> math, year -> 2017)]   |bar |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----+
```

Print Schema:

```
dff.printSchema();
root
 |-- address: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- docs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use function [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) combined with [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) to separate each row of your dataset.**

`from_json` exists since Spark 2.1 and transforms columns containing JSON string to Spark's structure. It takes two main arguments, the column containing the json and the json schema. Json schema can be defined using JSON string, DDL string or Spark's DataType.

Then, as your JSON represent an array, you use `explode` (existing since Spark 1.3) to transform a column containing an array to several rows each containing an element of the array.

So the complete code is:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

import java.util.HashMap;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json;

public class Functions {

  public static Dataset<Row> convertJson(Dataset<Row> jsonRows) {
    return jsonRows.withColumn("json", from_json(
        col("value"),
        "array<struct<name : string, address : struct<state : string, country : string>, docs : array<struct<subject: string, year: int>>>>",
        new HashMap<>()
      ))
      .withColumn("json", explode(col("json")))
      .select(col("json.*"));

  }
}
```

*Note: I chose DDL representation for schema*

So, if you apply previous `convertJson` function with your input:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"name": "foo", "address": {"state": "CA", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "english", "year": 2016}]}, {"name": "bar", "address": {"state": "OH", "country": "USA"}, "docs":[{"subject": "math", "year": 2017}]}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You get the following result dataframe:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+
|name|address  |docs             |
+----+---------+-----------------+
|foo |{CA, USA}|[{english, 2016}]|
|bar |{OH, USA}|[{math, 2017}]   |
+----+---------+-----------------+
```

having the following schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- docs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
```