# Save each row in Spark Dataframe into different file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I construct a spark DataFrame using with the following structure:

```
root
 |-- tickers: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I want to save each object in `price` into a separate JSON file and have each saved file using the corresponding `name` string as filename. Is there a way to implement this in a Python environment?

The most relevant solution I find is to repartition the dataframe into patitions of number of "rows" in dataframe, and use `.write.csv()` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890590/6158414). But this doesn't fit my need to save "rows" into separate files with different filenames.

To give more contexts. I'm using spark to call API and retrieve data in parallel. Each "row" in the spark dataframe is data query based on a unique values of `tickers`. The last step of my process is to save each query result separately. Would also appreciate it if someone have better way to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hom many rows per file?

Comment: I think you can get the first part of the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738678/3389828 (it is Java, I believe you can find a similar approach in Python) and then use https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890590/6158414 to write the CSVs.

Comment: `df.write.partitionBy("tickers").json(...)`, but writing a file per row, won't scale (just a number of required file descriptors can be a problem).

Comment: @thebluephantom each `price` element to be saved as one file, is an array of maps; length of array is around 1000, each map has 4 key-value pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write Spark **UDF** to save each object / element to a different CSV file.

Below is an example, which writes each row to a separate file. In your case, you just need to modify the UDF, to traverse through the elements of Price column and write them to a separate file.

```
>>> import csv
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
>>>
>>> list = [("1", "name1"), ("2", "name2"), ("3", "name3"), ("4", "name4")]
>>>
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(list, ["id", "name"])
>>>
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|name1|
|  2|name2|
|  3|name3|
|  4|name4|
+---+-----+

>>> # UDF that takes 2 columns and return if the file is saved successfully.
>>> def writeToCsv(x, y):
...   myData = [["id", "name"]]
...   fileName = x + '.csv'   # Modify the file name, add path if required.
...   myFile = open(fileName, 'w')
...   with myFile:
...     writer = csv.writer(myFile)
...     myData = myData + [[x, y]]
...     writer.writerows(myData)
...   return "SAVED"
...
>>>  # Register UDF with StringType Return type.
>>> save_udf = udf(writeToCsv, StringType())
>>>  # Invoke UDF for each row of the Dataframe.
... out_df = df.withColumn("processed", save_udf(df.id, df.name))
>>>
>>> # Check if all the rows are processed successfully.
>>> out_df.show() 
+---+-----+---------+
| id| name|processed|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|name1|    SAVED|
|  2|name2|    SAVED|
|  3|name3|    SAVED|
|  4|name4|    SAVED|
+---+-----+---------+
```